# Modeling Account to Account Type relationship

Tags: account

We are migrating to Salesforce from a SQL Server.
Our accounts have an associated table for account types, one to many relationship.
We use these to look up specific kinds of accounts. A (simplified) typical query might look like:

> Select * From Accounts Inner Join AccountTypes on Accounts.AccountID = AccountTypes.AccountID Where AccountTypes.Type like 'Dealership'

I am wondering if I can do this in Salesforce?
Can I create a new AccountType object that has an Account ID and a pick list item with all of the account types?

Comment: How does the ERD look in Salesforce? Should we assume you have a custom object `AccountTypes__c` or similar where a lookup relationship has been created?

Comment: The short answer is yes. It sounds like you may want an `AccountType__c` object that has a master-detail relationship with `Account` (so long as an AccountType cannot exist without being associated with an Account). If AccountType only exists to hold the type of Account though, a field may do the job. Either a picklist if an Account may have only one Type or a mulitselect picklist for more than one.

Comment: @nbrown Technically speaking an account type can't exist without an account. In practice it's a little different in the SQL server. Accounts, AccountTypes, and a joining table that links the two, but in practice it can easily be boiled down to "AccountTypes can't exist without accounts". I'm trying really hard to not carry my SQL "baggage" over to this, and try to learn the Correct way to do it in Salesforce. I mean, it possibly could be a multiselect picklist, but is that the best way for my situation? Is having a separate object better? Which is better to search against when they want all X?

Comment: It sounds like you want a picklist field unless you literally have hundreds of types (and at that point it can still work as a field, it just becomes difficult to manage and filter).